# Python string comparison using pymarc marc8_to_unicode no longer working

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, marc

My code imports a MARC file using MARCReader and compares a string against a list of acceptable answers. If the string from MARC has no match in my list, it gets added to an error list. This has worked for years in Python 2.7.4 installations on Windows 7 with no issue. I recently got a Windows 10 machine and installed Python 2.7.10, and now strings with non-standard characters fail that match. the issue is not Python 2.7.10 alone; I've installed every version from 2.7.4 through 2.7.10 on this new machine, and get the same problem. A new install of Python 2.7.10 on a Windows 7 machine also gets the problem.

I've trimmed out functions that aren't relevant, and I've dramatically trimmed the master list. In this example, "Académie des Sciences" is an existing repository, but "Acadm̌ie des Sciences" now appears in our list of new repositories.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from aipmarc import get_catdb, get_bibno, parse_date
from phfawstemplate import browsepage #, nutchpage, eadpage, titlespage
from pymarc import MARCReader, marc8_to_unicode
from time import strftime
from umlautsort import alafiling
import urllib2
import sys
import os
import string

def make_newrepos_list(list, fn):   # Create list of unexpected repositories found in the MArcout database dump
    output = "These new repositories are not yet included in the master list in phfaws.py. Please add the repository code (in place of ""NEWCODE*""), and the URL (in place of ""TEST""), and then add these lines to phfaws.py. Please keep the list alphabetical. \nYou can find repository codes at http://www.loc.gov/marc/organizations/ \n \n"
    for row in list:
        output = '%s    reposmasterlist.append([u"%s", "%s", "%s"])\n' % (output, row[0], row[1], row[2])

    fh = open(fn,'w')
    fh.write(output.encode("utf-8"))
    fh.close()

def main(marcfile):
    reader = MARCReader(file(marcfile))

    '''
    Creating list of preset repository codes.
    '''
    reposmasterlist =[[u"American Institute of Physics", "MdCpAIP", "http://www.aip.org/history/nbl/index.html"]]
    reposmasterlist.append([u"Académie des Sciences", "FrACADEMIE", "http://www.academie-sciences.fr/fr/Transmettre-les-connaissances/inventaires-des-fonds-d-archives-personnelles.html"])
    reposmasterlist.append([u"American Association for the Advancement of Science", "daaas", "http://archives.aaas.org/"])

    newreposcounter = 0
    newrepos = ""
    newreposlist = []

    findingaidcounter = 0
    reposcounter = 0

    for record in reader:
        if record['903']:                                   # Get only records where 903a="PHFAWS"
            phfawsfull = record.get_fields('903')
            for field in phfawsfull:
                phfawsnote = field['a']
                if 'PHFAWS' in phfawsnote:
                    if record['852'] is not None:           # Get only records where 852/repository is not blank
                        repository = record.get_fields('852')
                        for field in repository:
                            reposname = field['a']
                        reposname = marc8_to_unicode(reposname) # Convert repository name from MARC file to Unicode
                        reposname = reposname.rstrip('.,')
                        reposcode = None
                        reposurl = None
                        for row in reposmasterlist:             # Match field 852 repository against the master list. 
                            if row[0] == reposname:             # If it's in the master list, use the master list to populate our repository-related fields
                                reposcode = row[1]
                                reposurl = row[2]
                        if record['856'] is not None:       # Get only records where 856 is not blank and includes "online finding aid"
                            links = record.get_fields('856')
                            for field in links:
                                linksthree = field['3']
                                if linksthree is not None and "online finding aid" in linksthree:
                                    if reposcode == None:       # If this record's repository wasn't in the master list, add to list of new repositories
                                        newreposcounter += 1
                                        newrepos = '%s %s \n' % (newrepos, reposname)
                                        reposcode = "NEWCODE" + str(newreposcounter)
                                        reposurl = "TEST"
                                        reposmasterlist.append([reposname, reposcode, reposurl])
                                        newreposlist.append([reposname, reposcode, reposurl])
                                    human_url = field['u']
                                else:
                                    pass
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass

    # Output list of new repositories
    newreposlist.sort(key = lambda rep: rep[0])
    if newreposcounter != 0:
        status = '%d new repositories found. you must add information on these repositories, then run phfaws.py again. Please see the newly updated rewrepos.txt for details.' % (newreposcounter)
        sys.stderr.write(status)
        make_newrepos_list(newreposlist, 'newrepos.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        mf = sys.argv[1]
        sys.exit(main(mf))
    except IndexError:
        sys.exit('Usage: %s <marcfile>' % sys.argv[0])
```

Edit: I've found that simply commenting out the "reposname = marc8_to_unicode(reposname)" line gets me the results I want. I still don't understand why this is, since it was a necessary step before.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I've found that simply commenting out the "reposname = marc8_to_unicode(reposname)" line gets me the results I want. I still don't understand why this is, since it was a necessary step before.

This suggests to me that the encoding of strings in your database changed from MARC8 to Unicode. Have you upgraded your cataloging system recently?